# Создание Nuget пакета. Зависимость от сторонних библиотек

Tags: c#, nuget

Появилась задача, выделить функционал в Nuget пакеты. 
Но некоторый функционал зависит от сторонних dll пользователя.

Т.е. я могу включить эти dll в пакет, но тогда обновление dll пользователя не даст нужный эффект, использоваться будут библиотеки из пакета.

Есть ли какое-то известное решение?
Или возможно мне не хватает знаний, как это работает.

Сборки пользователя лежат примерно тут C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\***\v4.0_5.26.11165.714__*******.dll

Answer (score 0):

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL***\v4.0_5.26.11165.714__*******.dll

Из [Framework assembly references](https://github.com/NuGet/docs.microsoft.com-nuget/blob/master/docs/reference/nuspec.md#framework-assembly-references):

> Framework assemblies are those that are part of the .NET framework and
>   should already be in the global assembly cache (GAC) for any given
>   machine. By identifying those assemblies within the
>    element, a package can ensure that required
>   references are added to a project in the event that the project
>   doesn't have such references already. Such assemblies, of course, are
>   not included in a package directly.

Если пользовательские сборки находятся в `GAC`, то `frameworkAssemblies` похоже на то, что вам  нужно. Помимо приведенной документации можно посмотреть `.nuspec` файл проекта [nlog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/), он содержит множество таких определений.